# Qt: Error when reading the next character from file

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote the function that returns the next character from the QTextStream. There is:

```
QString peek(QTextStream *stream){
    QString __str = '\0';
    stream->seek(stream->pos() + 1);
    __str = stream->read(1);
    stream->seek(stream->pos() - 2);
    stream->flush();
    return  __str;
}
```

For example, I have a file:

```
abcde
```

When I tried to brought into the function result on the screen, output was correctly: 'b'.
But when I tried to output the next character and then the first character, like that:

```
/* Any function to output */(peek(file) + file->read(1));
```

Output was: "ca" instead "ba".

What's wrong?

Sorry, if it's stupid question and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I am not getting your question, what exactly you want to do. But watching you output expectation, I think you should change your expression `stream->seek(stream->pos() - 2);` to `stream->seek(stream->pos() - 1);`. Explain more if you can.

Comment: Stylistic note: This is not C, there's no reason for you to initialize `QString` like you do. It is also [invalid for you to use any names with double underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) - they are reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of argument evaluation in the expression below is not defined. It doesn't have to be left-to-right, not at all.

```
peek(file) + file->read(1)
```

In your case, it so happens that the read was performed first, advancing the position, and subsequently peek got a `'c'` instead of a `'b'`.

You need to break it down:

```
QString result = peek(file);
result += file->read(1);
Q_ASSERT(result == "ba");
```